# Automatic Push Notification from RSS feed

Tags: android, xml, rss, notifications

I want to know is there any way how I can automatically check for new feeds in RSS xml link and send a push notification regarding the new feed ?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com/) (which I created!) for the RSS polling aspects. We will send your server a notification (including the update!) every time a feed has a new entry. Then, you'll have to fanout that update to all of your app users using [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

Comment: Thank You for your response I'll check that.

Answer (score 0):

You need a server that regularly polls the RSS link, checks if a new feed as available, then sends a push notification to the client.

More technical details on Google Cloud Messaging can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

although this thread is a little old i thought it was worth adding that UrbanAirship have this feature available. You configure the feeds in the admin console and can use values in the feed in the resulting Push notification. It supports all major Push services too.

We've been using this for a year or so under the Free development account that gives you 1,000,000 pushes a month for free. BUT, they are closing this account type down in December.

Answer (score 0):

I created Feed Notifier

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.co.madhur.dashclockfeedlyextension

Works only for Feedly currently

Answer (score -2):

try creating a new flow in microsoft flow (rss -> push)